# How to make Robot Keyword return html result?

Tags: html, keyword, robotframework

I am trying to return html link as a result of Robot Keyword execution. But when I open log.html then instead of "http://www.google.com"
I see
" & lt ; a href=\"http://www.google.com\" & gt ; google &lt ; /a & gt ;"

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When keyword returned "*HTML* other html stuff" everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in [Log](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log) keyword accepts an optional keyword argument that says whether the message should be treated as HTML or not.

For example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
| Example of logging HTML  using keyword argument
| | log | <a href="http://...">Danger, Will Robinson!</a> | html=True
```

You can get a similar effect by using the `HTML` log level. This makes the message an INFO level message, but won't escape the html tags like with a normal INFO level message:

```
*** Test Cases ***
| Example of logging HTML using HTML log level
| | log | <a href="http://...">Danger, Will Robinson!</a> | HTML
```

Starting with robot framework 2.8 error messages can also contain HTML by beginning the error message with `*HTML*`.  For more information see [HTML in error messages](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#html-in-error-messages) in the robot framework user guide.

For example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
| Example of logging HTML
| | Example keyword that returns HTML error message

*** Keywords ***
| Example keyword that returns HTML error message
| | Fail | *HTML*<a href="http://...">Danger, Will Robinson!</a>
```